# How to run multiple instances of the same executable in IntelliJ idea Java project with different input files

Tags: testing, intellij-idea

I have around 30 input files that I like to run one after another every time I change something. Basically I fix something, and want to make sure that other test input files do not break. Currently I am using the RunConfiguration window to pass the name of my input file, but it would be so much easier if I could just run all of them at once and come back and view the output. The output is usually in a Window. I have tried to separate the input files with spaces, commas, and semicolon. I did see the links for running the instances in parallel, and I can try it but I really like to run the one after another. I am running IntelliJ 20192.4 on Windows 10. I do not have maven or Gradle installed yet, and test with sendng an input file to the java executable and read the file with file input stream library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JUnit or TestNG framework. Write a test or a test suite and run it with different options so that you can get [a nice view of the failed and succeeded tests in the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/test-runner-tab.html).

If you want to run multiple configuration in IntelliJ IDEA, use the **Before Launch** [section in the Run/Debug configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUaLb.png). You can add another configuration there. So you can have 30 run configurations one set be run before the launch of another. This way you can start just one configuration and it will run all the others sequentially.

Comment: This solution is definately along the lines of what I wanted, and I am not done reading everything. Just some immeidate feedback in case you want to correct me: I created another Run configuration, and configured the run before. Once I ran the main one, I had to close the output window before the next one runs. Is there a way to just click run and go away and come back and view the results? I am about to read the first link you shared now. btw, I became a big fan of IntelliJ idea. It is sooo user friendly. Love it.

Comment: Your app needs to finish before the next one runs, that's how the sequential run works.